# Do black holes have a maximum temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature

"Standard" black holes have usually a very low temperature if we assign their temperature to the Hawking radiation they are expected to emit and compare it to the one of an ideal black body. For a solar mass BH, this temperature is about $60 nK$. And it turns out that the relationship between the temperature and the mass of a BH is of the form $T \propto M^{-1}$. I.e. the more massive a BH is, the coldest it is.

On the other hand, it is known that BH "evaporates" by Hawkingly radiating, so eventually they should disappear. I wonder what would their temperature be at the moment they are disappearing. What do theoretical calculations say about it? I don't know whether quantum mechanics is involved (in case the BH becomes so small that it matters) or whether there is a theoretical low mass for a BH that's still so massive that the BH is still macroscopic, and so QM wouldn't be needed to answer the question.

In short, do black holes have a maximum temperature? If so, what is it equal to, in terms of fundamental constants? Does it depend on the angular momentum of the BH (I guess not)?

Comment: We need a quantum gravity theory to answer this properly. In fact, without quantum gravity we don't even know if Hawking radiation is real; the current derivation of Hawking radiation uses a semi-classical theory.

Comment: You may enjoy playing with the [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator).

Comment: We simply don't know. I recall a talk from a string theorist claiming that the end point of evaporation was a string in a highly excited state, but I think you should regard this as speculative to say the least.

Comment: Wouldn't a rough estimate just be the temperature associated to a Planck mass? Back of the envelope techniques are enough to give an idea of the scales involved, even if the actual correct computation would be more involved.

Comment: The Planck temperature, $\sqrt\frac{\hbar c^5}{G k^2}=1.4\times 10^{32}\text{K}$, seems like a reasonable guess for now.